# how spacing works in MUI. eg <Box component="section" py={[5, 5, 10]}>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

`<Box component="section" py={[5, 5, 10]}>`   what does [5,5,10] mean? I understand 'py={5}' means padding top and bottom are 5 unit.  How about '[5,5,10]'?

Comment: Are you sure its the API? https://mui.com/components/box/

Answer (score 0):

When you set 3 parameters, the first is for the top, the second is for the left and right, and the third is for the bottom.

So that means:
`padding-top:5`,
`padding-right:5`,
`padding-left:5`,
`padding-bottom:10`

This also applies to other styles such as margin, radius, etc.